# Parsing XML Document into Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, recursion, xml-parsing

I am attempting to create a multidimensional array of unlimited depth from an XML file.  I shall spare you the reasons why and just get straight to the point.

I would like the below code to parse an XML string, inserting all `<item>` and `<nest>` tags into an array.  Any `<item>` tags that are found directly under a `<nest>` tag should be be inserted into an array contained inside the main array.

On the recurisve call I have passed the key to a new array as the second parameter, so I would expect it to begin adding items to this new array.  This is not so, however.  If anybody could assist me in fixing the problem, I would appreciate it.

The code should run with a simple C+P.  Thank you.

```
class Parser
{
  static function subMenuRecursionArray($xml, $array = '', $itemcount = 1, $nestcount = 1)
  {
    foreach($xml->children() as $k => $v)
    {
        if ((string) $k == 'item')
        {
            $array["item$itemcount"]['text'] = (string) $v;
            $array["item$itemcount"]['command'] = (string) $v['command'];
            $itemcount++;
        }

        if ((string) $k == 'nest')
        {
            $array["nest$nestcount"] = array('name' => (string) $v['name'], 'items' => array());
            $nestcount++;

            self::subMenuRecursionArray($xml->nest, $array["nest".($nestcount-1)]['items'], $itemcount, $nestcount);
        }
    }
    return $array;
  }
}

$xml_fragment = '
<menu>
<item command="DefaultCommand">Main (Not nested 1)</item>
<item command="DefaultCommand">Main 2 (Not nested 2)</item>
<nest name="Cont">
    <item command="Contact">NESTED Contact 1</item>
    <item command="Contact">NESTED Contact 2</item>
  </nest>
</menu>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_fragment);
$array = Parser::subMenuRecursionArray($xml);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($array, 1) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: I do not get why anyone would need that. A DOMDocument-Object would be much more comfortable than an array.

Comment: by "`<item>` tags that are nested inside a `<nest>`" you mean all direct item children of a nest element or any descendants, e.g. any item somewhere in the hierarchy below a nest element?

Comment: elusive:  I'll save you the reasoning behind it!  If you could treat this as a hypothetical, that would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: i use a libray called xmlize to do this. i think it originally came as xmlize.inc or xmlize.php if you do a search.

Comment: Gordon: I mean direct item children.  Further nest tags could also be added and even further levels of recursion be required.  Thanks for pointing that out, I'll reword the topic.

Comment: @Peter can you add an example output pls

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this - notice that your call too subMenuRecursionArray is returning an array, but you aren't assigning that to anything - so it is just lost.

```
<?php
class Parser
{
  static function subMenuRecursionArray($xml, $array = '', $itemcount = 1, $nestcount = 1)
  {
    foreach($xml->children() as $k => $v)
    {
        if ((string) $k == 'item')
        {
            $array["item$itemcount"]['text'] = (string) $v;
            $array["item$itemcount"]['command'] = (string) $v['command'];
            $itemcount++;
        }

        if ((string) $k == 'nest')
        {
            $array["nest$nestcount"] = array('name' => (string) $v['name'], 'items' => array());
            $nestcount++;

            $array["nest$nestcount"]['items'] = self::subMenuRecursionArray($xml->nest, $array["nest".($nestcount-1)]['items'], $itemcount, $nestcount);
        }
    }
    return $array;
  }
}

$xml_fragment = '
<menu>
<item command="DefaultCommand">Main (Not nested 1)</item>
<item command="DefaultCommand">Main 2 (Not nested 2)</item>
<nest name="Cont">
    <item command="Contact">NESTED Contact 1</item>
    <item command="Contact">NESTED Contact 2</item>
  </nest>
</menu>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_fragment);
$array = Parser::subMenuRecursionArray($xml);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($array, 1) . '</pre>';
?>
```